# Como utilizar o botão power do celular?

Tags: android, android-studio, button, click

Gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar o botão power (liga e desliga) do celular em uma aplicação. Exemplo: Executando alguma função se apertado o botão três vezes seguidas.
Se possível gostaria de algum exemplo.
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, adicione o seguinte no seu Android Manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />`

Em seguida, na sua activity que vai capturar os eventos de clique, coloque o seguinte código:

**Identificando Clique Simples**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {

        // Faça alguma coisa ...

        event.startTracking(); // Necessário para identificar cliques longos

        return true;
   }

   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Identificando Clique Longo**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {

        // Faça alguma coisa...

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Obs.:**

- **Resposta copiada e adaptada de:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android
- **Autor da resposta original**: [JT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321888/jt)